# how can i use v-for loop in my vuejs project

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, v-for, v-model

I have a loop and I have 4 inputs in this loop. I want to give the id values from each loop separately to my 4 inputs, how do I do that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKvsn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH2EX.png)

i am running a loop there is only one input this input is values ​​from a loop how do i provide value retention for each individual using a v-model

Comment: To get the best answer you need to provide the structure of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic Vuejs. You need to return data as follows:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{ message: 'Foo' }, { message: 'Bar' }]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then you create a v-for loop:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <input :id="index" v-model="item.message" />
  </div>
</template>
```

So in your case it might looks something like:

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      altinFiyati: Object
    },
    data() {
      return {
        altinCount: this.altinFiyati,
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Then in your v-for loop you would connect whatever data to your v-model input:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in altinCount">
        <input :id="index" v-model="item.message" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hello, When I enter data into the input, the data I entered and the current sales price of gold should multiply with the input and the data I entered, but since I have only one input, the input is required.
I don't know how to configure

Comment: This would have to be calculated with function that you would use. You need to share your code to get better help.

Answer (score 0):

What went wrong? Is your component properly configured to use v-model? Additionally, since you are presently iterating over that item, you do not need to pass in listOfItems[index]. Instead, you may just refer to the item with the v-model="item" prefix.

Comment: Hello. When I enter data into the input, the data I entered and the current sales price of gold should multiply with the input and the data I entered, but since I have only one input, the input is required.
I don't know how to configure

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @ric.jacqueline